# How to detect if Cursor position change in textView swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone tell me how to detect if cursor position change in textview?

Comment: You can get help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift

Comment: No.i want to know how to detect if cursor position change not the how to get position of cursor

Comment: Got answer.we can detect by textViewDidChangeSelection Method.

Comment: Could you please add and accept you own correct answer. I guess I was just as blind when I didn't see textViewDidChangeSelection delegate method. And that duplicate mark by Anbu without link not helping either. You helped, thanks :)