# How can I set UITextView selectedTextRange with animation and scroll position

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview

I've been trying to figure out a way to set the cursor to the bottom of a long UITextView with animation. Setting it wasn't too difficult, in fact this answer covers it very well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922332/563381

However, animating it isn't so easy. There isn't a `setSelectedTextRange(animated:)` that I can find. Setting it inside a `UIView.animate...` block doesn't seem to do anything. The best I've been able to come up with is to animate the scroll manually then in the completion set the `selectedTextRange`. However this is fragile, often looks choppy, and seems on occasion to not work at all.

When you set `selectedTextRange` it does jump to that location. If there was a way to avoid that jump the animation might be smoother and at least would be less fragile since it wouldn't require a delay and you could use `setContentOffset(animated)` without needing to wait to set the `selectedTextRange`.

The other option is to find a way to cause the `selectedTextRange` jump to be animated itself. On this front I tried the trick of disabling scrolling before and reenabling after but that didn't seem to work for me. Guessing that has changed in later versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setContentOffset(_, animated:) and detect the end of the animation with scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation and set the cursor like so:

```
// The action to scroll down
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {

    let offset = self.textView.contentSize.height - self.textView.frame.height
    self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset), animated: true)
}

// Setting the cursor down
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = self.textView.contentSize.height - self.textView.frame.height

    if scrollView.contentOffset == CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset) {
        let newPosition = textView.endOfDocument
        self.textView.selectedTextRange = self.textView.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
    }
}
```

You will need to add UITextViewDelegate to your view controller and set the textView delegate:

```
textView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Using `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView:)` is a little better than waiting for a completion block because I don't have to worry about how long the animation is. But I'd love something cleaner that wouldn't leave the cursor at the top while this was animating.

Comment: I don't see how it matter that the cursor appears after the animation rather than during the animation. You dont want your user typing while the animation is going I think? So you should actually disable the cursor while the animation is going. @RyanPoolos

Comment: @RyanPoolos If this helped you please accept the answer