# Find out when cursor is moved in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, cursor-position

I have a TextField with money text "1234,00"

The tail ",00" I added by code, user don't have to type it.

But I don't want user to edit ",00". So I want user can not move cursor to ",00".

I find out **TextView** have `textViewDidChangeSelection:` but it don't have in **TextField**.

So how can I get notify about cursor change in TextField?

Comment: Override textFieldShouldChangeCharacterInRange , set textfield text over there by checking on 'string' argument and return false from there

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya that way user still can move cursor

Comment: did you see that https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922332/4601900

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I mean when user finish input, there will be ",00" at the end. And then user tap TextField again to edit (user haven't input any new text), user still can move cursor to ",00". I want prevent user to do that (moving cursor to ",00").

Answer (score 0):

I have to hardcode by adding Label on top of TextField. Although it will be wrong if text is longer than TextField width