# iOS Added programmatically UITextField does not scroll text to cursor position while editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have added UITextFields programmatically. Here is an example:

```
addingItemView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))
let itemNameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: textFieldWidth, height: 20))
itemNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
itemNameTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("itemName", comment: "")
itemNameTextField.keyboardType = .default
itemNameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
itemNameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
itemNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 3
itemNameTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
itemNameTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
itemNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(assignValueToItemName), for: .editingDidEnd)

addingItemView.addSubview(itemNameTextField)
```

The issue is: when user is typing more characters than UITextField length, text is not being horizontally scrolled to the left like it happens by default with UITextFields that were added in Storyboard. So user is not able to see what is he typing there.

I have tried to find respective property in UITextField class and in storyboard inspector - no luck. Checked some answers here, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift), but was not able to find how to scroll text.

Bad example (cursor is not visible, but it's screenshot issue, coz it's blinking):

[image]

Good example (TextField added in Storyboard, cursor is not visible, but it's screenshot issue, coz it's blinking):

[image]

Kindly advise what am I missing here? Should I implement EditingChanged method and scroll text programmatically? I tried, but did not understand how to do it. I guess moving cursor to position is not the same thing.

Comment: Have u tried adding it with constraints in code ???

Comment: No I didn't... Will try, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My particular issue was resolved by increasing height size from 20 to 25. Most probably it happened because iOS was not able to adjust text because of font size and textfield height.

```
let itemNameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: textFieldWidth, height: 25))
```

Answer (score 3):

If textField's height is less than text font size, the textField will not scroll to cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
addingItemView.addSubview(itemNameTextField)
itemNameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
itemNameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: textFieldWidth).isActive = true
itemNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
itemNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addingItemView .leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
itemNameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addingItemView .topAnchor, constant:40).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code is valid but gave me the same result. And I suddenly found the cause... I changed height from 20 to 25 and it started working as expected. Not sure why it happened, but it did.