# How to fix Text Field which is covered by Corner Radius

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I check out this answer, helpful, but didn't get what I want: [Getting and Setting Cursor Position of UITextField and UITextView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift).

In the attribute inspector, I set Placeholder to " ____ First Name", and it fixes the left alignment of the text since it is moved to the right a bit. But I don't think that is the proper way to do it. Also, I didn't quite get the cursor position explanation from the above answer.

```
     func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
        {
            let arbitraryValue: Int = 5
            if let newPosition = textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, offset: arbitraryValue) {
                textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)

            // ....

            }
        }
```

[image]

The thing is even after somehow I figured it out to make it work, the cursor is moved 5 characters to right. When I removed the text, the cursor moves back into the left corner.

**But what I exactly want is the whole textField to move to the right so that it doesn't get covered with CornerRadius like above.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did without adding any codes.

- **I placed the Views underneath the textFields.**
- **I made the Views make extra width on both sides.**
- **I set the Views color that of textFields.**
- **Then I give them corner radius property.**

[image]

And if we look at it closely, we can see those edges. They make me cringe.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the padding on the text field itself.

Swift:

```
 //Changes the text padding
 override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15))
 }
 //Changes the placeholder
 override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15))
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using override on function? It will give you error "Method does not override any method from its superclass".