# How to place cursor at the end of formatted number after copy-paste?

Tags: ios, swift

so here's my problem.
I'm using UITextField for payment card number and I'm formatting this number on **.editingChanged** so that it always has format of 4 digits with space between them. (*Example: 5213 0000 0000 1234*).

The problem is that when I copy-paste the (unformatted) number from sms for example, the cursor will occur after the 16th character (*Example: 5213 0000 0000 1|234*).

I need the cursor to be at the end, but so far nothing works for me.
I tried setting the position after the formatting in the same func that's fired on **.editingChanged** (I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift) as tutorial), but nothing really happend.

I also tried to make my custom UITextField where I overrided the **closestPosition** func so that cursor will be always at the end and user couln't move it, but even after that cursor appears at the 16th position after copy-paste.

Does anybody know how to deal with this?
Thanks for all the help. <3

(note: We are supporting only 16 digits card numbers)

Comment: try to use input mask https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can update the cursor position using the `selectedTextRange` property of the textfield (which is part of the `UITextInput` protocol that it adopts).

Update that property after you've modified the textfield's `text` property:

```
// Add spaces as required here then:

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let end = self.textField.endOfDocument
    let range = self.textField.textRange(from: end, to: end)
    self.textField.selectedTextRange = range
}
```

**Note:** you usually have to schedule that to be done on the next run loop if you've modified the textfield's `text` string immediately before (hence the use of the `main` `DispatchQueue`). Not sure why that is, but it’s possibly a `UIKit` bug.

The `UITextInput` documentation can be found here (always a good place to start looking if you want to do something with a textfield beyond accessing its text):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput

Comment: The `main` `DispatchQueue` does it for me! Thank you so much!