# How to place cursor at the end of text whenever the user touches on UITextField containing that text?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In my custom UITextField the user can place an e-mail by touching on "+" button or by writing it from keyboard. The problem is when the e-mail is added through "+" button and then, someone wants to add another e-mail, this time by writing it from keyboard, the cursor instead of being at the end of the text, highlights previously written mails, but it cannot be placed at the end of the text - which is what I would like. I hope what I wrote is understandable. Anyways, do you know a way of implementing this?

I've already tried setting keyboard time and selecting text range but it brought me no good

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift

Comment: Yes, I've seen this but this doesn't work for me. It often happens that if there are let's say 4 mails in the textField, which were added by "+" and then, one touches on the textField, it often happens that the text selected is of one the mails and I simply cannot put the cursor at the end to add something from keyboard. I just don't want that e-mail highlighting whenever textField is touched and normal writing style

Comment: Maybe try to set that textfield do not recognize email, to just look at it as plain text. I think you can find that in IB.

Comment: Edit your question, post the code you have tried and the issues you are facing