# IOS. How to put cursor to the end of UITextFiled

Tags: ios, swift

I want to put cursor (indicator point) to the end of text field.

I have the following code, but it does nothing

`textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)`

```html
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "selection_sub"), object: nil)
        imitateSingleSelection()
        textField.text = textField.text?.toLocalNumberFormatFromServer()
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
    }
```

Is there a way to put cursor to the end of text field?

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZvNy.png)

[This is my TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4FP7.png)

Comment: try textField.becomeFirstResponder() to give focus to the text field and make the keyboard appear

Comment: I tried it. I also tried this code in the same place 
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument) 
And it works - selects all text in text field. It seems to me selectedTextRange doesn't work if range has zero length

Comment: check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift

Comment: I tried it - doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please add a snipet of your code and the textfield or the responder you are trying to use this on for a better idea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.