# Cursor Position in Centered aligned TextView is wrong in IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, uitextview, iqkeyboardmanager

I have used IQKeyboardManagerSwift in my project. I have a Centered aligned TextView and the problem is Cursor is positioned at center instead of at the beginning of Placeholder text.

TextField with centered alignment is working fine, it shows cursor at the beginning but issue is in Centered aligned TextView.

How do I get cursor at the beginning of placeholder text in Centered aligned TextView ? (see attached screenshot - Write Description TextView)
https://ibb.co/5RWNzTW

I already have gone through this link [Getting and Setting Cursor Position of UITextField and UITextView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift) but no luck! It would be great if anyone could help! Thank You!